# How can I filter integer_range field by current time on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

My mapping is like this for index:

```
"availableHours" : {
   "type" : "integer_range"
}
```

A sample is:

```
"availableHours" : [
   {
        "gte" : "61000",
        "lte" : "62200"
   },
   {
        "gte" : "71100",
        "lte" : "72300"
   },
]
```

`Format: which day of the week/hour/minute`

I want to filter integer_range field by the current time. But I can't give the current time. I should get the current time from ElasticSearch.

Is it possible to do that with a query?

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

I don't sure what you are trying to get, but I think this page will help you if you could give more explained example I think I could give you the exact query you looking for

Comment: For example:
- Today is Saturday. İt means the 6th day of the week. 
- And the time is 09.00 pm. My time format is 24h. It means 21.00.

So my filter is "62100".
My query is:
`GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "availableHours": "62100"
        }}}}}
` But the problem is I cant calculate 62100. I have to do this with elastic. I mean I should use a query similar to the one below:
`GET  my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now"
      }}}}`

Comment: The query is not clear, if you want all the data in the last day for example, why you didn’t use the query gte: now/d - 1d? All the data with the same time zone?